# Why does my array keep rendering the same number for each variable?

Tags: android, arrays, for-loop, iterator, libgdx

I have a for loop that is looping through an array of rectangles as they appear. For each new rectangle that is added to the array a sprite is drawn on top of it. I want each sprite drawn on top of the rectangles to have its own variable that changes the sprite drawing. While on the screen mostly every rectangle should have a different sprite drawn on it  ------------------------------------I cant figure out how to give each sprite its own variable with out giving the same one to all of the other sprites. This code ends up drawing the new same sprite on every rectangle. Here is what i have so far..

```
  int arrayplace = 0;

 for(Rectangle  rain: rectangleArray) { 

    numberArray.add(arrayPlace, MathUtils.random(3);
    //adds a variable to a certain spot on the array
    // picks random# within range given
    arrayplace++;           

          if (numberArray.get(arrayPlace)==1){
              spritebatch.draw(spriteOne, rain.x, rain.y);
          };
          if (numberArray.get(arrayPlace)==2){
              spritebatch.draw(spriteTwo, rain.x, rain.y);
          }
          if (numberArray.get(arrayPlace)==3){
              spritebatch.draw(spriteThree, rain.x, rain.y);
          }
  }
```

Comment: For some strange reason I couldn't find `MathUtils` class in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html)! How did you use it?

Comment: @iturki Mathutils is in a library known as libgdx

Comment: Would you mind putting the link in your question.

Comment: Yeah sorry let me change that

Comment: You changed `MathUtils` to `Math`? which class is that?   java.lang.Math?

Comment: Here's the libGDX MathUtils source: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/math/MathUtils.java#L136

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is:

```
arrayplace++;
```

You increment `arrayplace` too early, so it points to an index behind the value you added.

Answer (score -1):

The way random generators work, they generate a series of numbers based on a "seed" value. The first number in the series is going to be the same given the same seed. Are you using your random function correctly? Most likely the value of "10" you are passing to the random method is the seed. Do you need to call some other function to give you the next random number? Check you random function documentation. Here is the Java random doc : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random(long) Refer to the usage of seed parameter to the constructor and to the method next() or nextInt()

Going further, I think you need to change the "seed" to the random generator every time you enter the loop, instead of using a constant 10.

Comment: Good theory, but the `10` is not the random seed, its the range.  See: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/math/MathUtils.java#L136

Comment: I updated my question and code to make more sense sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score -1):

I guess the reason you are getting the same random number is that you are initializing the class in each loop. so, you are generating the first number which will be the same each time.

- Try to initialize MathUtils object **outside the for-loop**:

  ```
  MathUtils m = new MathUtils();
  ```
- And inside the loop, use this line to generate a number:

  ```
  PointlessRect.x = m.random(10);
  ```

Hope this will work

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using code from a library i had as you can see in the revision.

Comment: This is a good theory, but the libGDX MathUtil class only contains static methods.  See: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/math/MathUtils.java#L136

Comment: I updated my question and code to make more sense sorry for the confusion.